# After migrate magento to newer server with SQLi and PHP5.5 module can't connect database

Tags: mysqli, deprecated, mysql-connect

After migrate magento the shop works fine but when I want to pay the redirect doesn't work and got fatal error. In log file the following error appeared:

> ERR (3): Deprecated functionality: mysql_connect(): The mysql
>   extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli
>   or PDO instead  in
>   /home/debloeme/domains/debloemenkas.nl/public_html/NIEUWWEBSHOP/idealcheckout/includes/library.php
>   on line 1162 2015-04-02T17:04:44+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

The webshop is migrated to another ipadres  with same URL and same db name etc.
On the other server the payment service worked. Is it something with the newer PHP version?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using module https://github.com/SanderSander/magento-ideal-checkout/
This module creates new connection to mysql database and it is using *mysql_connect* which is deprecated call in new php versions. On your new server you have different (newer) version of php.

This call creates deprecated warning but this isn't problem that broke your installation. You need to find where you have to configure database credentials for this module - it seems that it has different config that magento default (app/etc/local.xml)